# Adding JavaScript to Qualtrics to control cursor position on page advance

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

End Goal: 
Capture 1 minute 'snapshots' of an essay as it is being composed. 
Make it unapparent to users that data is being collected before final submit.

Current Approach:
-Multiple copies of same question on separate pages. 
-1 min timer on each page auto advances to next page, saving current text.
-'Default Choice' feature pipes text from previous page to populate next page.

Problem:
Cursor position is lost on page advance. User has to click back into text field and place cursor at end of text.

Question:
Is it possible to use JavaScript to automatically place the cursor at the end of the piped text after each auto page advance when the timer expires? 
-Less important, can suppress the page fade/flash on page advance?

[EDIT] I'm beginning to think this is the wrong approach. If the user is typing when the timer expires, the last few characters are lost. So even if I fix the cursor issue, the data loss will still be a problem.

Is there a way to do this within a single page/question? The text could still be stored in other (hidden) questions, but it might be better to keep the user in the same field the entire time.

Comment: Do users have a set amount of time to complete the essay? Otherwise I imagine you could run into issues with a limited number of pages.

Comment: Yes, it will be limited to 5 -10 minutes depending on the essay.

Comment: Just saw your edit.  You can have a JavaScript use setInterval to save the answer to embedded variable(s). I'll let you take a shot at writing the script.